# How to get access to Evernote api key because of username?

Tags: evernote

I am unable to request for evernote Api key as I am not able to find the username.
[image]

It is not present in the user profile page of evernote.
Please tell me where can I find it or any other way to get the api access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your account Settings > General > Evernote Email Address, you'll find your username as the beginning of your Evernote email address.

[see evernote forum](https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/70025-how-to-find-my-usernameemail-on-my-ios-app/)